# Update User Outside `users#edit` Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to create a simple button that updates the boolean `user` attribute `notify_generator` from its default value of `false` to `true` when the user submits a form.  The form is on my `home#construction` page:

```
  <% if current_user.notify_generator == false %>
    <h1 class="">Want to know when it's ready?</h1>
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>  <<<<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
      <%= f.hidden_field :notify_generator, value: true %>
      <%= f.submit "Keep Me In The Loop", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <h1>You're set! We'll let you know when the generator is up and running!</h1>
  <% end %>
```

The `home_controller` is as follows:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :historical_only
  skip_before_action :historical_only, except: [:history]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:construction, :generator]

  def index
  end

  def history
  end

  def about
  end

  def gear
  end

  def generator
  end

  def construction
    @user = current_user
  end

  private
  def historical_only
    unless current_user && ( current_user.access_historical == true || current_user.admin == true )
      flash[:error] = "You must be a historical BurnIt member to see those goodies."
      render action: "index"
    end
  end
end
```

Right now, when I try to access the `home#construction` page I get `undefined method 'user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc236054a0>:0x007fbc24495470>`.  I think this is symptomatic for trying to update a user from outside the domain of the registrations controller.  I'm using the `devise` gem, if that makes a difference.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                          devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                      devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                     devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                            registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                   registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                           registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                              registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                                   registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                   registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                   registrations#destroy
```

Comment: Hey could you add your `homes#constructions` view?

Comment: @oreoluwa, the `erb` at the top is from that view.  The only other code on that view is irrelevant images.

Comment: oh! I see. Could you post the complete error message?

Comment: @oreoluwa, the full error message is in the bottom paragraph of the post, but I indicated which line of the `home#construction` erb the error was called on.

Comment: The error seems to be related to your `@user` not being an instance of User which is strange. Could you check the value(with byebug or pry) of your `@user`

Comment: I did check the user value and the info for my current_user came back correctly.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `rake routes | grep user`?

Comment: Why is it seeing the value of your @user as `#<#<Class:0x007fbc236054a0>:0x007fbc24495470>`? It should see something similar to: `#<User:0x03kd0i303n3u94>`

Comment: @oreoluwa, is this because it's not under the jurisdiction of the `devise` controller, it's under the `home` controller?

Comment: @oreoluwa `#<#<Class:0x007fbc236054a0>:0x007fbc24495470>` is the view, not the User.

Comment: You're right, I didn't immediately see the rake routes' result above. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices:  You can either either define your own UsersController, or you can use Devise's existing RegistrationsController.

I won't explain how to implement UsersController--that's standard MVC and I'm sure you've done it before.

But if you want to leverage existing devise code, let's take a look at how devise does this [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/85bcbdf18b5c3a5ecf254412539bbb31aa1a54f0/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb#L3):

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, 
  url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
```

Notice that you need to pass the option `url: registration_path(resource_name)`.  In this case, that resolves to `user_registration_path`, so you can just use `url: user_registration_path`.  The `resource` part is specific to devise controllers--because you're using `@user` instead, you don't need the `as: resource_name` because Rails can infer that the resource name is `user` from the name of the instance variable (`@user`).

You will probably need to customize your permitted parameters.  See the [devise README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) for how to do this.

Comment: Before opting for this option, I'd probably want to know why the user isn't probably set in the first place

Comment: The user is set according to the OP's comment immediately following your comment on the question.

Comment: I tried this, but it threw up an error for `resource`.  When I changed that to `:resource` I still got `undefined local variable or method 'resource_name' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc236054a0>:0x007fbc233e5080>`.

Comment: I saw that, but still the question isn't answered why is it seeing an instance of `#<#<Class:0x007fbc236054a0>:0x007fbc24495470>` rather than something like: `#<User:0x03kd0i303n3u94>`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think it's best to always jump to patching an error, rather than understand why the error in the first place.

Comment: @Liz The only thing you need to change is adding the `url` option.  I will clarify in the answer.

Comment: @oreoluwa `@user` is a `User`.  `user_path` is an undefined method in the view.  The view is being interpreted in the context of an anonymous class.

Comment: I changed it to `<%= form_for(@user, url: edit_user_registration(@user)) do |f| %>`, but I'm still getting `undefined method 'edit_user_registration' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc236054a0>:0x007fbc1b0cdd00>`.

Comment: `user_registration_path`, not `edit_user_registration`

Comment: That makes the view actually display, but when I click the button I still get `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

Comment: Add `html: { method: :put }` as in the example I pasted from devise.

Comment: You're right, I didn't immediately see the `rake routes`' result above. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: With `    <%= form_for(@user, url: user_registration_path(@user), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>` I still get `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

Comment: Change `user_registration_path(@user)` to `user_registration_path`--It doesn't need an argument.

Comment: And if that solves it, then you probably don't need the `html: { method: :put }`

Comment: Oh goodness.  It's now dragging me into my actual `users#edit` page saying "Current password can't be blank".  That's another devise thing isn't it?

Comment: I added `protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end` to the `registrations_controller` and it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: Okay, it doesn't actually update the attribute on the production server, only on `localhost`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably because of param sanitization.  As I mentioned in the Answer, see the devise README.